# How to write list output to a text file in Python

Tags: python, list, text

I've run this code but it only writes in the text file the first directory in /home

```
for item in os.listdir('/home'):
    text_file_1 = open('/tmp/home_dir.txt', 'wb')
    text_file_1.write('%s\n' % item)
    text_file_1.close()
```

Comment: Well you close the file after you write one line.

Comment: it should actually write the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open the file outside the loop. Otherwise you "start over" every time you open it

Context managers (`with` statement) are the preferred way to open files

```
with open('/tmp/home_dir.txt', 'w') as  text_file_1:
    for item in os.listdir('/home'):
        text_file_1.write('%s\n' % item)
```

Comment: or, `text_file_1.writelines(fname + '\n' for fname in os.listdir('/home'))`

Comment: That will certainly work as well, but I think this is clearer for beginners

Comment: So which one do you recommend?

Comment: @mgilson's answer is shorter, and mine is clearer. Whichever you feel comfortable with. Functionally they're nearly identical.

Comment: @mhlester -- Gotta learn comprehensions sometime.  No better time than right now... :-)

Comment: And should I use wb or just w?

Comment: the `b` is for binary. since you're writing text it's generally better to just use `w`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it's the last item from os.listdir().

try this:

```
text_file_1 = open('/tmp/home_dir.txt', 'w')

for item in os.listdir('/home'):
    text_file_1.write('%s\n' % item)

text_file_1.close()
```

Or this:

```
for item in os.listdir('/home'):
    text_file_1 = open('/tmp/home_dir.txt', 'a')
    text_file_1.write('%s\n' % item)
    text_file_1.close()
```

When you open the new file handle and write to the file with 'w', it completely overwrites what was originally in it.

'a' allows you to append to the file.

I would recommend my first solution; opening and closing files is costly. If you're going to rapidly loop over items to write to a file you may as well keep it open.